# gym.error.NameNotFound: Environment `tic_tac_toe:tictactoe doesn't exist

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, tic-tac-toe, openai-gym

I am following a tutorial to create my own openAI gym environment for Tic Tac Toe but have run into the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\geniu\tictactoeproj\Code\test.py", line 4, in <module>
    env = gym.make('tic_tac_toe:tictactoe')
  File "C:\Users\geniu\tictactoeproj\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py", line 676, in make
    return registry.make(id, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\geniu\tictactoeproj\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py", line 490, in make
    versions = self.env_specs.versions(namespace, name)
  File "C:\Users\geniu\tictactoeproj\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py", line 220, in versions
    self._assert_name_exists(namespace, name)
  File "C:\Users\geniu\tictactoeproj\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py", line 297, in _assert_name_exists
    raise error.NameNotFound(message)
gym.error.NameNotFound: Environment `tic_tac_toe:tictactoe` doesn't exist.
```

Here is the code that is producing the error:

```
import gym

env = gym.make('tic_tac_toe:tictactoe-v0')
```

Here is the code for the init file where the id was created:

```
from gym.envs.registration import register

register(id="tictactoe-v0", entry_point="tic_tac_toe.envs:TicTacToeEnv")
```

I'm not sure why this is happening. I have followed the exact same naming format that was in the tutorial. I'm not sure whether something went wrong with registration of the environment or if I am using the wrong name when calling gym.make. I have also tried doing `gym.make('tictactoe-v0')` which seems to follow the format of other gym environments better but that doesn't work either and produces the same error.